# how to manage fullscreen iframe by button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an iframe:

```
....
     <div style="height:500px;width:500px;background:black" class="embed-responsive">
        <iframe src="widget.html" width="100%" height="100%" class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
....
```

In the widget.html, I have a button to open an close the fullscreen.

```
function closeFullScreen () {

        if(document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }                
     }

function openFullScreen ()  {
      var iframe = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

        if (iframe.requestFullscreen) { /* Firefox */
                iframe.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
                iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            } else if (iframe.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
                iframe.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (iframe.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
                iframe.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
}
```

I am able to open the fulllscreen but not closing it?

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Impossible to see without where you are executing closeFullScreen - for example in unbeforeunload or something

Comment: I am calling the function from the content of the iframe...

Comment: I solved using query-fullscreen-plugin: https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin/blob/master/demo/index.html

Answer (score 1):

from MDN :

> The read-only fullscreenEnabled property on the Document interface indicates whether or not full-screen mode is available.

source:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenEnabled)

Essentially means that the call you are making with `document.fullscreenEnabled` doesn't really check if there is an active iFrame that has a full screen open. Rather, it is asking "Does the document have full-screen mode available?".